# Get all files with specified extension node.js

Tags: node.js, file, directory

I am using node.js. I want to loop through all files with extension .coffee,
but I have nowhere found an example.

Comment: What OS are you using? A *nix flavour, Mac or Windows?

Comment: @NZD I'm using Arch Linux, but I will be happy if it works on Windows and Mac, too.

Comment: You are probably looking for [`fs.readdir()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_callback) and perhaps [`path.extname()`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_extname_p).

Comment: @jfriend00 and the use regex to validate if it is *.coffee? Isn't this a bit slow, because it reads all unneeded files, too?

Comment: @DimoChanev - Something is going to read all the file entries from disk anyway so the speed difference whether you do it in node.js or it's done in the OS is not likely a big difference.  You can use `path.extname()` to parse off the extension to see if it's `.coffee`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following function will return all the files in the specified directory with the regex provided.

**Function**

```
var path = require('path'), fs=require('fs');

function fromDir(startPath,filter,callback){

    //console.log('Starting from dir '+startPath+'/');

    if (!fs.existsSync(startPath)){
        console.log("no dir ",startPath);
        return;
    }

    var files=fs.readdirSync(startPath);
    for(var i=0;i<files.length;i++){
        var filename=path.join(startPath,files[i]);
        var stat = fs.lstatSync(filename);
        if (stat.isDirectory()){
            fromDir(filename,filter,callback); //recurse
        }
        else if (filter.test(filename)) callback(filename);
    };
};
```

**Usage**

```
fromDir('../LiteScript',/\.coffee$/,function(filename){
    console.log('-- found: ',filename);
});
```

Comment: see the jfriend00's comment for easyer way of doing this, But is is working well, too :)